# Combining dataframe column values with lists to create a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a file 'customers.txt' with data of what items each customer bought and has following format:

```
0   customer_21: item_575,item_2703,...
1   customer_11: item_454,item_158,...
2   customer_10: item_1760,item_613,...
3   customer_4: item_1545,item_1312,...
4   customer_6: item_2608,item_1062,...
5   customer_23: item_1659,item_2610,...
6   customer_14: item_2858,item_2007,...
7
```

And another csv file 'stores.txt' which have data of items which are in each store. I have read and made a dataframe as follows:

```
customers_df = pd.DataFrame(index = stores.Item.unique(),
            columns = [line.split(':')[0] for line in open('customers.txt').readlines()])
for customer in customers_df.columns:
    for item in customers_df.index:
        customers_df.loc[item, customer] = item in customers_dict[customer]
```

But as I add data for more customers, the code slows down exponentially. Is there an efficient way to achieve that? Ultimate goal is to have all information regarding which users bought a particular item or not in one place where I can do further analyses. Files are being updated automatically and as of now it takes almost 6-7 minutes for now.

Comment: You may have a typo:  is 'users.txt' the same as 'customers.txt' ?

Comment: Ohh yess its customers.txt

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) in this case:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

df = pd.read_csv(filenames, sep=":\s*", header=None, names=["cust", "items"])

res = (pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(mlb.fit_transform(df["items"].str.split(",")), 
                                         index=df.index, 
                                         columns=mlb.classes_)
         .set_index(df["cust"]))
```

---

result:

```
In [24]: res
Out[24]:
             item_1062  item_1312  item_1545  item_158  item_1659  ...  item_2703  item_2858  item_454  item_575  \
cust                                                               ...
customer_21          0          0          0         0          0  ...          1          0         0         1
customer_11          0          0          0         1          0  ...          0          0         1         0
customer_10          0          0          0         0          0  ...          0          0         0         0
customer_4           0          1          1         0          0  ...          0          0         0         0
customer_6           1          0          0         0          0  ...          0          0         0         0
customer_23          0          0          0         0          1  ...          0          0         0         0
customer_14          0          0          0         0          0  ...          0          1         0         0

             item_613
cust
customer_21         0
customer_11         0
customer_10         1
customer_4          0
customer_6          0
customer_23         0
customer_14         0

[7 rows x 14 columns]

In [25]: res.dtypes
Out[25]:
item_1062    Sparse[int32, 0]
item_1312    Sparse[int32, 0]
item_1545    Sparse[int32, 0]
item_158     Sparse[int32, 0]
item_1659    Sparse[int32, 0]
item_1760    Sparse[int32, 0]
item_2007    Sparse[int32, 0]
item_2608    Sparse[int32, 0]
item_2610    Sparse[int32, 0]
item_2703    Sparse[int32, 0]
item_2858    Sparse[int32, 0]
item_454     Sparse[int32, 0]
item_575     Sparse[int32, 0]
item_613     Sparse[int32, 0]
dtype: object
```